# Magento 1.x Multistore product image not showing in in store views

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-images, product-list

Magento 1.x Multistore product image not showing in in store views

Image showing assigned in the back end.

I've tried by assigning product images to store view level and setting as global value but no result.

It is showing placeholder instead of product image.

Please help.

Comment: What you see if you inspect the image url `<img src="...">`? you problem is just for certain store view or also for the global one ?

Comment: It shows place holder image.